# T4 Template Save as Unicode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, unicode, t4

I use Template - Generator architect as Oleg Sych said to generate some code by T4, but there is some problems in using Unicode, I have some Persian characters after generate all of the Persian characters displayed as question mark.

This is my files: Template:

```
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#+
public class DALTable : Template
{

    public override string TransformText()
    {

        //My Template

    }
```

Generator:

```
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" #>
<#@ include file="DALTable.tt" #>
<#+
public class TableDALGenerator : Generator
{
    public DALTable DALTableTemplate = new DALTable();

    protected override void RunCore()
{
        this.DALTableTemplate.Table = table;
        this.DALTableTemplate.RenderToFile("DAL.cs");
    }
 }
```

And Script:

```
<#@ template language="C#v4" hostspecific="True" debug="True" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" encoding="UTF8" #>
<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>
<#@ include file="TableDALGenerator.tt" #>
<#
    TableDALGenerator TableDALGen = new TableDALGenerator();
    //Pass Parameters
    TableORMGen.Run();
#>
```

As Oleg Sych said I set Unicode in output as you see in this line: `<#@ output extension=".cs" encoding="UTF8" #>` also I save as all of this 3 files with Unicode `utf8`
but the problem still remain, where is the problem? what another thing remain that I must do that?

**Update**

I found that none of my new generated files (DAL.cs) not saved as `UTF8` all of them saved by `ANSI` encoding. what need to do to save my files by `UTF8` encoding?

Comment: in `<#@ output extension=".log" encoding="UTF-8" #>`, `UTF8` should be `UTF-8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<#@output` directive applies to the direct output of the T4 file.
You need to alter your template so its output is UTF8

```
public class DALTable : Template 
{ 
    public DALTable()
    {
        Output.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    } 

    public override string TransformText() 
    ...
```

Comment: I ask a related question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838142/put-all-methods-in-one-tt-file-and-use-it-in-another-t4-files-in-codetemplates would you please check it

Comment: I note that `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` renders the Unicode BOM (Byte-order-mark) by default, which (generally) should not be used at all. Unfortunately there isn't a public `UTF8NoBom` singleton in the .NET Framework but you can use `Output.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding( encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true );`

Answer (score 4):

As per MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586943.aspx), to do this in the `output` element, you need to say `encoding="utf-8"`, so with the hyphen (the letter casing does not appear to make a difference).