# Put All methods in one .tt file and use it in another t4 files in CodeTemplates of MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, t4

I use ASP.NET MVC 3 [Custom CodeTemplates](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx) I need to put some methods in one t4 file and then use it in all my t4 templates.

So this is my general.tt file:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Entity" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Linq" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.ComponentModel" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Linq.Mapping" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffolding.BuiltIn" #>

<#+ 
public class XXD {
    public string getitNow(){
        return "Yup thats it!";
    }
}
 #>
```

Then I use it in create.tt file like this:

```
<#@ include file="general.tt" #>

...

<#+

private string GetitNow(){
   XXD xx = new XXD();
   return xx.getitNow();
}
```

but there is an error when I want to Add View Use create template:

**error**: Loading the included file 'general.tt' returned a null or empty string. The transformation will not be run.

So where is the problem? what is your suggestion to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last time I checked, the MVC scaffolding still used a custom implementation of the ITextTemplatingEngineHost, which implements the include directive differently than the ITextTemplating service in Visual Studio. I suggest for you to submit a [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio) bug, describe the problem you are experiencing and ask to change the T4 implementation in MVC to the built-in ITextTemplating service, which does not have this and other limitations.

Comment: Oleg is correct.
I can imagine maybe working around this by having one regular T4 template which outputs your MVC-specific template by including your two fragments.  IN other words, a template to generate a template.  However, this is not going to be very approachable for someone new walking up to your project for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

That normally means that the file isn't found. Is `general.tt` in a different path to `create.tt`?

Comment: Yes, also I have intellisense when I want define `XXD` class or `getitNow()` method that both of them defined in `general.tt`